# How to see code coverage result in Visual Studio 2022 professional

Tags: visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2022 professional. Used Xunit, wrote unit cases in the project. How can I see the code coverage percentage.

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

I am not sure how to see the code coverage

Comment: Try "Fine Code Coverage" extension.

Comment: Tried 'Fine Code Coverae' But still not showing  any coverage after run all unit test cases. Is it issue with VS 2022 professional?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest `Fine code coverage` extension. Navigate to `Extensions -> Manage extension` and type `Fine code coverage` in Search control on the top of the right:

[image]

After installing restart the studio. `Fine code coverage` window you can find at `View -> Other Windows`:

[image]

It provides pretty simple for understanding statistics of code coverage:

[image]